# how to perform rolling mean using if condition in group by operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add a code wherein, if the difference between current date and the minimum date of the id column is more than 3 months, the rolling mean should be for a 21 days window, else it should be for a 7 days window.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,2,2,1],
                  'date' : ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-10', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-13', '2023-09-11'],
                  'rev' : np.random.randint(100, 150, 5)})
dt
    id  date        rev
0   1   2023-09-01  144
1   1   2023-09-10  147
2   2   2023-01-01  100
3   2   2023-01-13  103
4   1   2023-09-11  103
```

Code I am trying to get the rolling mean is:

```
dt.groupby('id').transform(lambda x : x['rev'].rolling(window = '21D', min_periods = 1).mean() if pd.to_datetime('today') - x['date'].min() >= 90 else x['rev'].rolling(window = '7D', min_periods = 1).mean())
```

But I am getting `KeyError: 'date'` error.

Could someone please help on how to get the rolling means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `on` keyword in [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
dt['rev'] = (dt.groupby('id', group_keys=False)
               .apply(lambda x : x.rolling(window='21D', on='date', min_periods = 1)['rev'].mean()
                      if pd.to_datetime('today') - x['date'].min() >= pd.Timedelta('90D')
                      else x.rolling(window = '7D', on='date', min_periods = 1)['rev'].mean()
                     )
            )
```

Output:

```
   id       date    rev
0   1 2023-09-01  144.0
1   1 2023-09-10  147.0
2   2 2023-01-01  100.0
3   2 2023-01-13  101.5
4   1 2023-09-11  125.0
```

Comment: could you please let me know why `apply` works and `transform` doesn't work

Comment: @KarthikS because `transform` doesn't allow access to other columns, it operates separately on each column while `apply` passes the full DataFrame to the function.

Comment: I have a generic query, the `for` loop runs fine with I run it as it is, but while building a function, the same `for` loop takes lot of time when it's inside the function block, is it normal for Python/Pandas to work that way?

Comment: @KarthikS hard to answer without a clear example, I'd encourage you to open a new question with all details. In general you should avoid for loops in pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and compare days by [`Timedelta.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html):

```
dt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['date'])

out = (dt.set_index('date')
         .groupby('id')['rev']
         .apply(lambda x : x.rolling(window = '21D', min_periods = 1).mean() 
                          if (pd.to_datetime('today') - x.index.min()).days >= 90 
                          else x.rolling(window = '7D', min_periods = 1).mean()))

print (out)
id  date      
1   2023-09-01    144.0
    2023-09-10    147.0
    2023-09-11    125.0
2   2023-01-01    100.0
    2023-01-13    101.5
Name: rev, dtype: float64
```

With `transform`:

```
dt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['date'])

out = (dt.set_index('date')
         .groupby('id')['rev']
         .transform(lambda x : x.rolling(window = '21D', min_periods = 1).mean() 
                           if (pd.to_datetime('today') - x.index.min()).days >= 90 
                           else x.rolling(window = '7D', min_periods = 1).mean()))

print (out)
date
2023-09-01    144.0
2023-09-10    147.0
2023-01-01    100.0
2023-01-13    101.5
2023-09-11    125.0
Name: rev, dtype: float64
```